# Интеграция VoIP телефонии на iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Нужна реализация VoIP (только голосовая связь). Посоветуйте фришную SDK, которую пропустит Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам не писал, но мой коллега хвалил вот это https://code.google.com/p/idoubs/ . Только они кажется писали интерпрайс приложение и задачи прохода в аппстор перед ними не стояло

Comment: Спасибо, но - GNU GPL v3. Такое не пустят в аппстор.

Comment: Вам нужно готовое решение, или "полуфабрикат"?

Comment: @Fidel, больше года с вопроса прошло, либо человек уже решил проблему, либо она не актуальна

Comment: @aknew Допустил не внимательность, не посмотрел на дату, когда вопрос задан был, простите.

Comment: @aknew нет, задачу не решил, но к сожалению уже не актуальна. Разве что в будущем